# Google script how to use value from a spreadsheet cell as URL in URLFetchApp.fetch()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a total newbie to Google scriptwriting, but I am trying to get a specific function to work. 
I created this function to have the script download a file from a specific hyperlink to my Google Drive, but the URLFetchApp.fetch() will not work if I want to use a specific Sheets cell value as the URL.

Is it possible to use a reference in this function (as shown in my code) instead of a literal hyperlink? (i.e. URLFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com") )

```
function saveFile() {
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,1).getValue();
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

Comment: Yes, if the value is an actual url. Are you able to read values from the desired sheet?

Comment: I just found out that the fetch function appears to automatically add http:// in front of anything I try to use as a URL, so when I removed https:// from my URL it DID work... :)